# About candle lighting

Tags: minhag

What is the meaning of the minhag of lighting a candle for leiluy nishmat or refuah shleima?
Today for example we light a candle for rabbi shimon

Comment: Who is 'we'? I know I haven't lit any candles today at all for any purpose.

Comment: @doubleAA the sefaradim, at least.

Comment: Please always include all information in the question by [edit]ing. Also you may want to check out our [policy about jargon/Hebrew usage](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1606/759) for use in your future posts.